# How do we get maximum value from table without using Max,Min or Order by Clause in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have one table has Salary has 3 columns and I want to get maximum value from this table without using Max, Min or order by clause.

Data

Salary has three fields - `ID,Name,Amount`
value of Amount - `100,70,80,400,300`

I need to get value of 400 from this data.

I know Select max(Amount) from Salary, But i need without max,min or Order by clause.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This must be homework of some kind, please tag it as such. Then describe what ideas you've had to solve it up until now.

Comment: Tell me, if you find a solution not using cursors. But why tagging optimization?

Comment: If you cannot use neither MIN/MAX, nor ORDER BY, there's no way to impose any ordering on your data and thus you won't be able to find the min and max value (other than scanning through all the rows and just programmatically keeping track of the min/max values......)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM salary s1
WHERE s1.amount > ALL (SELECT s2.amount 
                       FROM salary s2 
                       WHERE s2.id <> s1.id);
```

But I doubt that it will be faster than using max()

Answer (score 4):

Given this is a theoretical question only and `NOT AT ALL` practical... here's my answer.

ALL is a cool solution for SQL Server (see notes below). For the rest, and any ANSI compliant RDBMS

```
SELECT *
FROM salary s1
WHERE not exists (SELECT *
                  FROM salary s2 
                  WHERE s2.id <> s1.id AND s2.Amount > s1.Amount);
```

It is a bit better than the ALL answer though, since it will show all the TIES if there are multiple with the Max(salary) whereas Martin's will not return any results if there are TIES at the MAX.

It *may also run faster* due to `not exists` quitting per s1 row for any matches found in the correlated subquery.

Comment: +1 I forgot about ties. The `not exists` works out less inefficient than `all` for large numbers of rows but not for the reason you give I think. (the plans have anti semi joins for both) Rather because `not exists` is a triangular join and `all` is nearly a cross join. Against a numbers table on my laptop with 1,000,000 rows I got `ALL` (28181 ms, 5272760 reads) `NOT EXISTS` (1911 ms, 3190772 reads) `@VARIABLE` (499 ms, 1614 reads) `MAX` (0 ms, 3 reads)

Comment: @Martin it is even less than triangular. It will be fully triangular only when the correlated query finds nothing. Once it can invalidate the outer query (Exist found), it can quit that branch immediately.  This is the same reason why Exists () on a highly dense subquery is much faster than cross join + filter later.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @amount int

SELECT @amount = CASE WHEN @amount > amount THEN @amount ELSE amount END 
FROM yourtable


select @amount
```

This is most definitely not an optimization though as (assuming an index on `amount`) `MAX` could stop scanning after the first result whereas this must scan all records.

It is still more efficient than this though

```
SELECT *
FROM salary s1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM salary s2 WHERE s2.amount  > s1.amount)
```

Which in turn is massively more efficient than `ALL`

[image: Plans]